# Pulseaudio: wait for devices on start?

Tags: linux, audio, systemd, pulse-audio

Based on [this guide](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-to-make-pulseaudio-run-once-at-boot-for-all-your-users), I set up pulseaudio on my Raspberry Pi to run in system mode. Here's how my systemd service file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio Daemon
After=sound.target
Requires=sound.target

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --disallow-exit --no-cpu-limit --daemonize=no --system --realtime --disallow-module-loading --log-target=journal -vvvv
```

However, I'm not getting any sound - according to the logs, when pulseaudio starts, udev-detect reports "Found 0 cards." and I only get the null sink. Running `systemctl --system restart pulseaudio.service` fixes this and my audio device is correctly detected.

Is there any way to tell pulseaudio to wait until a device is detected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telling that PulseAudio won't be very useful. It can already detect hotplugged devices just fine on its own; however, due to `--disallow-module-loading` it is no longer able to *use* the devices, since it's forbidden from loading `module-alsa-card` after a device is detected. (Arguably module-udev-detect should be exempt from this restriction…)

You can tell *systemd* to delay starting pulseaudio.service until a specific device is ready, by listing the corresponding `.device` unit name in this unit's `After=`, e.g.:

```
[Unit]
After=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1b.0-sound-card0.device
```

Comment: Ah, how annoying - didn't even guess `--disallow-module-loading` is the culprit. Just removing that seems easiest.

Comment: Quick update: adding a sound device to `After` is pointless if I already have `sound.target` - turns out that all sound devices have `sound.target` under `Wants` according to `systemd-analyze`.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, `alsa-restore.service` should be in `After` - this way, I can load alsa directly and I don't need device detection in the first place.

Comment: But they don't have it under `Before`, do they? Either way, that's **not** what `sound.target` is for – anything like "all sound devices were discovered" is impossible to implement in a hotpluggable system anyway. The target is for starting _userspace_ sound components, and indeed it seems like PulseAudio should have Before=sound.target, not as After=.

Comment: Interesting - but my (hypothetical) goal is to be able to load pulse on startup with `--disallow-module-loading` - it seems ALSA is what I should wait for, unless I'm misunderstanding something else? The hotpluggable setup works, but I need to drop `--disallow-module-loading` - in that case, I'm guessing `sound.target` only need to be under `Requires` and it's not needed to have it in `After`?

Comment: There is no point in waiting for ALSA "in general". (All device initialization happens in kernel; `alsa-restore.service` merely loads volume levels from disk to _already-detected_ audio devices.) If you manually configure PA's `module-alsa-card`, all you need to wait for is the card device itself.

Comment: So, the problem here is that module-alsa-card requires a device parameter and `load-module module-alsa-card device=0` causes pulse to fail with an error saying the device doesn't exist. Any insight?